# in PHP - what is the difference in use of ' ' and " "

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Hi all

I am very new to PHP and I wanted to know what is the difference in use of ' ' and " " ?

Thanks

Comment: See the [strings chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in the manual

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Comment: If something is so basic you *know* you can easily look it up, *don't waste other people's time*, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes evaluate the content of the string, the single quotes don't.

```
$var = 123;
echo 'This is the value of my var: $var'; // output: This is the value of my var: $var
echo "This is the value of my var: $var"; // output: This is the value of my var: 123
```

It WAS a perfomance issue too, 'cause evaluation time affects the interpreter, but nowadays with the current (minimum) hardware it's not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
$name='RkReddy';

echo "$name hi hello"; //op-RkReddy hi hello

echo '$name hi hello';//op-$name hi hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much, but when using double quotes you can use a PHP variable inside the string, and the string will output the variable's value. When using a single quote it will output the variable's name without parsing the actual value. IE.:

```
$something = "A nice little variable";
echo "$something is printed out"; //output: A nice little variable is printed out
echo '$something is not printed out'; //output: $something is not printed out
```

Hope this helps!